# Android SDK Emulator wont open in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, virtual-device-manager

I Have the whole Eclipse Android sdk working. Everything but the virtual device manager. I downloaded to Bundle from androids website, installed java JDK into the eclipse folder, then housed the entire bundle in a folder on my desktop. When I go to hit the "Androd Virtual Device Manager" button, nothing happens. Nothing at all. It used to work ( i could never run the program though, I could just open the window to make anew device)

Comment: try android avd from the command line

Comment: What platform are you running on? Are there any error messages when you click on the button? What did you change since it stopped working?

Comment: I have restarted my pc, and Im on windows 7 64bit. There are no errors. When the device creator window would pop up, and i would hit start, it would not work. So I reinstalled it, and this has been happening. I reinstalled the bundle 3 times.

Comment: Do you see any messages under 'Console' or 'LogCat'?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have properly installed/updated sdk to the latest version

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Try running the C:\android-sdk-windows\AVD Manager

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am running windows 7 home basic on my laptop.

Do the following steps :

1. You need to first copy your entire java folder(the one containing the java sdk) to a location where administrator rights are not required.
2. Change the path variable by going to the advanced tab in *My Computers* and adding a new environment variable.
3. once you do that, go to the folder where you have your entire android sdk and in its parent folder search for the file named android.bat.
4. go to the properties of the file found and copy the entire address
5. go to cmd and type-cd"the path you copied".
6. you are in the tools folder and now type android.bat and press enter..
7. it takes some time like 30-40 sec and then opens our beloved sdk manager, and you are there.